# jquery get value in the last instance parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am struggling to get the regular expression working correctly.

Basically, I have the string looks like below feeding to a function to get the value in the last parenthesis

```
This is a test (ABC) and (500%)
```

This function only get the value in the first parenthesis. Please help with the Reg pattern of how to get the value in the last parenthesis of the string.

```
function getRate(str, hiddenElement)
{
    //alert(str);
    $("#" + hiddenElement).val('');
    var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
    var matches = regExp.exec(str);
    var matchedStr = (matches[1]);  
    //alert(matchedStr)
    if (matchedStr != "")
    {
        matchedStr = matchedStr.replace("%", "");
        alert("Matched: " + matchedStr);
        $("#" + hiddenElement).val(matchedStr);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `var regExp = /.*\(([^)]+)\)/;` -- prefix with `.*`.

Comment: It works perfect.  Thank you